# play back generated sounds

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I want to capture audio (in my case from `getUserMedia`) and play it back. I'm able to push a bunch of AudioBuffers to an array like so:

```
var recorder = audio_context.createJavaScriptNode(256, 2, 2);
recorder.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
  recorded.push(e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0));
  // or just:
  // recorded.push(e.inputBuffer);
};
recorder.connect(audio_context.destination);
```

But then how do I play the buffers in the `recorded` array?

A way to merge these into one buffer and play it with `createBufferSource`?

A different approach altogether?

Comment: Are you trying to record single-channel or stereo audio from getUserMedia?

Comment: anything will do :)

I got something working [1] thanks to this recording mini lib [2] that exports to wav. But feels overkillish to export to wav just for playback 


[1] http://www.phpied.com/files/webaudio/record.html
[2] https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

Comment: oh yeah, I see you found my Recorderjs library. Maybe I'll add a feature to export as an AudioBuffer, hmm...

Answer (score 2):

Once you're done recording the audio, you should be able to do the following:

```
var bufferIndex = 0;
recorder.onaudioprocess = function (e) {
  var outputData = e.outputbuffer.getChannelData(0);
  var recordedData = recorded[bufferIndex];
  for (var i = 0; i < recordedData.length; i++) {
    outputData[i] = recordedData[i];
  });
  bufferIndex++;
}
```

(You can probably make that simpler/cleaner; this was just for illustration purposes)

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me, will try again, maybe I had something wrong elsewhere :) Thanks!

Comment: That's odd. I didn't test it though so I may be wrong. Is your recorder connected to the destination? If so, I'll test it later and see if I did something wrong.

Comment: The thing to remember with this solution is that you need to continually cycle through the Float32Arrays stored in `recorded`. So each time `onaudioprocess` is called, you need to move to the next buffer and use that as `recordedData`. Additionally, you could probably use the `.set` method instead of manually iterating over the output buffer array.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to `set`--That would probably make this faster (and shorter).

Comment: @Stoyan are you seeing any errors in the console, by the way? Or is there any indication of what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the simplest way to do this is, as you suggested, merging them into a single AudioBuffer and playing that through an AudioBufferSourceNode. I would start by creating a new AudioBuffer object via the `context.createBuffer` method, specifically the version that takes numberOfChannels, length, and sampleRate as arguments. To calculate length (which is in seconds), you'll need to know the size of all your sample arrays combined... you may want to simply keep a running total of this as you capture them (something like `recLength += currentBuffer.length`). You can then determine the length by dividing the total number of samples by the sample rate. Sample rate can be determined via `context.sampleRate`.

Once you've created a new AudioBuffer object with the proper parameters, you simply need to copy the arrays you've saved (your `recorded` array) into the AudioBuffer's channel data array. This is a fairly simple two step process:

1. Retrieve the underlying channel data via the AudioBuffer's `getChannelData(channel)` method
2. Iterate through your `recorded` array and copy your saved data into the channel data array via the `.set(array, offset)` method (see [the MDN Float32Array docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_typed_arrays/Float32Array) for more info). Your code would look something like `channelData.set(currArray, currOffset)` with `currOffset` increasing by the length of each stored array.

**Note:** if you're recording two channels of audio, you'll have two arrays of recorded samples and you'll have to perform the above two steps for each channel (0 and 1), copying over the corresponding array.

If done correctly, you'll have an AudioBuffer which you can slot into an AudioBufferSourceNode and play back as you see fit.

Comment: If you don't have too long of a recording, this does work well. However, the API discourages using them for long sounds (since you have a limit on the number of samples as well...). I may be misunderstanding something, though.