# Webaudio API ScriptProcessorNode how to output signal

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'd like to process audio with ScriptProcessorNode Interface but I'm not able to write output buffer.

```
var node = context.createScriptProcessor(256,1,1);
node.onaudioprocess = function (e){
        var inputBuffer = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
}
```

I get data from getChannelData but how to send them to the outputbuffer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output buffer is stored in `e.outputBuffer`. Basically, you can change the data within this to set what the output gets.

E.g. to fill a buffer with random numbers

```
node.onaudioprocess = function (e) {
  var output = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
  for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    output[i] = Math.random();
    // Math.random() sends random numbers, but you can make 
    // that be anything you want
  }
}
```

- For example: [play back generated sounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128107/play-back-generated-sounds)

Comment: Thanks. I figured out my problem. Gain was too low so I could not hear processed signal..